# Cypress:Unable to work with else if condition and won't execute any step but timer is running

Tags: javascript, iframe, cypress

Unable to work with below else if condition and always stuck with if

```
cy.get("#result").iframeOnload().find(".text-error").invoke('text').as('iframeText');
            cy.get('@iframeText').then((iframeText) => {
                if(iframeText === expectedFailText){
                    ResultPage
                    .getResultErrorMessage()
                    .should("have.text", expectedFailText);
                }
                else if(expectedPassText){
                    ResultPage
                    .getResultPassedMessage()
                    .should("have.text", expectedPassText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Well what is the actual value of `iframeText` and of `expectedFailText`?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/182668/pointy the values of iframetext is getting from the element i.e You have not achieved the pass rate  and expectedFailText is You have not achieved the pass rate both are same only

Comment: what is inside `expectedPassText`? if this is a falsey value, the `else` will never be executed. Maybe you meant `else if(iframeText === expectedPassText){`?

Comment: @Kaddath the expectedPassText is "You passed"

Comment: @JagannathaMv well if both values are the same, why would you expect the `if` part not to run?

Comment: @Pointy Thing is i have Two texts one is Pass and fail , Suppose my user pass i need to validate those text and if failed  i validate the  failed text. But the value of the element for pass and fail is both are different that too it is inside the iframe

Answer (score 5):

It's a great example of how **not to write a test!**

You can only get one outcome, so are you planning to run it repeatedly hoping to cover both `if()` and `else()` with random results?

I suggest you start by splitting into two tests and set up **precursor conditions** to give you `passText` and `failText` respectively.

On a technical note, you cannot use an alias with an `<iframe>`. That's because the iframe has `contentWindow` and the alias will attempt to requery it, and fail.

Whatever is in `.iframeOnload()`, get rid of it and use the `cypress-iframe` plugin. Use it to first establish that the iframe has loaded, then run a normal test inside the `<iframe>` scope.

A rough example

```js
it('tests the pass text', () => {
  // precursor condition - setup for pass
  cy.enter('#my-iframe').then(getBody => {
    getBody().find(".text-error").invoke('text')
      .should('have.text', expectedPassText)
  })
})

it('tests the fail text', () => {
  // precursor condition - setup for fail
  cy.enter('#my-iframe').then(getBody => {
    getBody().find(".text-error").invoke('text')
      .should('have.text', expectedFailText)
  })
})
```

Comment: i got the solution by the way i partially added my logic here any way.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/21950818/zoe you are just separated test  with different logic . This solution of you never works. Because of some  stack overflow reputation  points don't comment and edit simply .